# Clicking on a link to display images

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to programming and working on a website that displays a list of links. Clicking on a specific link, displays some images. Now I'm wondering if I need to add an event listener to each link because what if I have a 100 links, does that mean I'll have to write 100 event listeners?

```
document.getElementById("monkwhosold").addEventListener("click",function() {disp_img(/MonkWhoSold)});
```

The above event listener is an example, where a user clicks one of the links and a disp_img function is called with the img folder path passed as a parameter.

Comment: Are you aware of jQuery? Is it an option for you to include jQuery? If so, tasks like this become a lot easier.

Comment: Dont add 100 event listeners. Instead use data attribute . Give all links a data-url attribute then give them the urls . And open them accordingly when clicked

Comment: why don't you use jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to solve this. Here's one.

```
<a href="#" class="image-link" data-url="/MonkWhoSold">
<a href="#" class="image-link" data-url="/AnotherImage">
...
```

Then in JavaScript you can write:

```
// find all <a> tags with class of 'image-link'
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a.image-link');

// loop through them all
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
{
    var link = links[i];
    // listen for the click event
    link.addEventListener('click', function()
    {
        // on click, show the image using the URL from the data-url attribute
        disp_img(link.data.url);
    });
}
```

This doesn't use any jQuery. If you're starting out programming these days, I think it's worth learning the DOM stuff directly. Once upon a time this wasn't easy or didn't work across browsers, and jQuery was really valuable. That's less true nowadays, though it still can be quite convenient.

In this code there are only three functions you really need to learn:

- `querySelectorAll` to find all elements that match some CSS selector
- `addEventListener` to attach a callback function to a particular event
- `element.data` to access data stored in `data-foo="bar"` attributes of the HTML

Other than that it's `for`, `function` and other simple elements of the language.

Comment: Why is it worth learning the 'DOM stuff' directly? I disagree, I think as long as you have an understanding about how jQuery is selecting elements it's fine to use it, and encourages resourcefulness in utilizing the libraries available, i.e. the wheels you're about to reinvent.

Comment: @DeeMac, each to their own. My opinion is that the best parts of jQuery made it into the ECMAscript spec (`querySelector` and friends), albeit in a slightly more verbose way. Honestly the code above isn't that long if you take out the comments I put there because OP said they were learning programming. And if you ever want to be good at something, you should learn about the level beneath the one you're using -- for example you can't be a knowledgeable biologist without understanding some chemistry.

Comment: Fair enough, I see your point. +1 anyway, I didn't know about `querySelectorAll` (I'm probably making your point for you here!).

Comment: @DeeMac, another great thing about learning the DOM API directly is that you can try out new stuff sooner, without having to wait for jQuery to support it. Soon we'll have [for...of loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) which will make the above code even cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I recommend to you to use something like jQuery for many reasons.

Suppose you have a series of images in this way:

```
<div id="myLinks">
   <a href="...">link1</a>
   <a href="...">link2</a>
   ...
</div>
```

Using

```
$('#myLinks a').on('click', function() {disp_img($(this).attr("href"))});
```

It's like the code you've wrote using the plain Javascript. But, like the yours, in this way you're creating an handler for each image (very slow).

But I recommend to use this one:

```
$('#myLinks').on('click', 'a', function() {disp_img($(this).attr("href"))});
```

Because in this way you're using only one listener for all the links. That is more performant!

Answer (score -1):

If you have many links, acquire the elements by class.

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("imageLink").addEventListener("click", function () { 
      //do something
});
```

JQuery

```
$('.imageLink').on('click', function () {
      //do something
});
```

That way you have one function, not one function per link.